# pip can't find pip

Tags: python, pip

My ubuntu 14.04 LTS installation is in an odd state. I got it there by attempting to install python3.5 and python3.4 simultaneously.

I installed python3.5 and python3.5-dev, from [deadsnakes](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes), but I'm getting the error:

```
$ pip3.5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3.5", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==7.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'pip3.5')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-28.2.0-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 567, in load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-28.2.0-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2604, in load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-28.2.0-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2264, in load
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-28.2.0-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2270, in resolve
ImportError: No module named 'pip'
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

After installing python 3.5, I was able to install pip as follows :
$sudo apt install python3-pip

After this step, when I call which pip3 I get the following :
$which pip3
$/usr/bin/pip3

So, I can use it as follows :
$pip3

Answer (score 0):

`pip` sometimes has a problem setting read permissions for the modules it installs. Try this:

`sudo chmod -R a+rX /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/`